# how to run ionic project with php back-end in mobile

Tags: php, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an ionic application with php backend ( database in phpMyAdmin), how can I run it on my phone android and test it please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to run the ionic application with PHP backend on mobile.
If you are working with wampServer,Go to the path: wampServer->Apache ->hhtp.conf,  and change the configuration of this file, by going to , and add (Allow from all) at the end. and then, you can run your application in mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax.

Javascript ajax to your server hosting your php files to send/receive data.

Comment: How do I ?know that I am a beginner. Is that  I have to make a lot of changes in the application so that I can fix this please?

Comment: Lookup and play around with how to use ajax. If you are learning do it on a website first to see how it works then move the javascript into the app to test. Remember once it is in the app you must use full url's to public accessible domains.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
ionic run android
```

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/testing.html

Comment: This command is working, but I can't display data from database to my phone!

Comment: I use PHP, and I can display data with : ionic serve command in web, but when I run it on my phone, I don't get Data

Comment: Is the backend public available? Are you on the same network as your backend?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, But I activated an access point on my , and phone and I connected on my laptop, but I didn't get data from database

Comment: can you reach you backend with your browser on your phone for example?

Comment: yes, In my browser with ionic serve command , it works , but not on my phone